# Matcher regex not matching pattern

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have created a method which I am hoping to find @gmail.com within a set string, with testing passing in for example stackoverflow@gmail.com the method returns false.

I've searched but I am unsure what i am missing, as I am using .matches() is matches.find() necessary?

```
public final static boolean isGmail(String s) {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\W|^)[\\w.+\\-]*@gmail.com(\\W|$)");
    System.out.println(pattern + "            pp  ");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
    System.out.println(m + "            pp  ");
    boolean b = m.matches();
    System.out.println(b + "            pp  ");
    return b;
}
```

}

Regex I am very new to, so that could be the issue I accept.

Comment: [This](http://ideone.com/dYCCou) would indicate that your method returns `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you need is:

```
[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@gmail\.com
```

---

```
public final static boolean isGmail(String s) {
    return s.matches("(?i).*?[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@gmail\\.com.*");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find "@gmail.com" within string, you should use **find()** method to achieve correct behaviour.

The difference between match() and find() is, that match() method attempts to match the **entire region** of the tested string against pattern, while find() attempts to find **next subsequence** of the tested string that matches the pattern (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html). Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use a regex for this, you can just do

```
public final static boolean isGmail(String s) {
    return s.indexOf("@gmail.com") > -1;
}
```